# BAT Command to Delete specific sub-folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a follow bat command which will delete unnecessary files when i give respective file extension

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Change the path and the extension...
DEL /s /f /q "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\test\*.pdf"
DEL /s /f /q "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\test\*.csv"
ECHO Are you sure ? Press a key to continue.
PAUSE > NUL
ECHO Done
PAUSE
```

I am in need to insert specific sub-folder to delete along with files. Assume specific sub-folder name may be **abc**

Can any body help me on this how to insert "delete specific sub-folder"

Comment: do you want to insert a subfolder or delete a subfolder?

Comment: @DJK: They probably mean "insert [another DEL command with a] specific sub-folder to delete along with files".

Comment: Why is your script asking `Are you sure?` *after* deleting the files?

Comment: Are you really asking how to delete a *specific sub-folder* or how to delete *all sub-folders with a specific name*?

Comment: need of deletion of a subfolder

Comment: deletion of specific subfolder and not all sub-folders

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RD` command to remove a (sub)directory. Since a directory may not be empty, you may want to add the `/S` switch to remove the entire directory tree. And since you are also going to use the command in a batch script, you may need the `/Q` switch as well, to avoid the confirmation prompt.

So add a command like this to your script:

```
RD /S /Q "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\test\Specific\Subfolder"
```

Comment: Hi, showing below error The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Are you sure ? Press a key to continue.

Comment: Then probably you specified an incorrect filename, directory name, or volume label. Did you copy the command verbatim? It was meant to be an example of how to use the command. Specifically, the directory name was an example.

Comment: okay, when i tested as per above BAT, files were deleting, and sub-folders were not deleting. Path / directory given same for files & sub-folder. kindly correct me were i did wrnong    @ECHO OFF
REM Change the path and the extension...
DEL /s /f /q "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\test\*.pdf"
DEL /s /f /q "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\test\*.snip"
DEL /s /f /q "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\test\*.csv"
DEL /s /f /q "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\test\*.db"
RD /s /q "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\test\*.img"
ECHO Are you sure ? Press a key to continue.
PAUSE > NUL
ECHO Done
PAUSE

Comment: I see now. `RD` doesn't accept masks, it only works with a specific name. It wasn't obvious from your question that you wanted to use a *mask* to specify which subfolders to delete. I'll think of a different solution. Please edit your question to clarify your intention.